# Windows SharePoint Services (WSS) 3.0 Migrating default Internal database to SQL Server

Tags: wss

Does anyone know the best way to do that? I couldn't find any articles on this subject.

Comment: Not really a programming question - try http://sharepointoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options to do this. The first (Microsoft-approved) way of doing it is to just move the content databases, but leave the config database on the internal database. The technet documentation for doing that is here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287738.aspx

If you want to move the config database as well, you have 2 options. The first (probably less headache-inducing) method is to basically backup your content databases, remove the WIDB from the computer, create a new farm pointing to your SQL Server database, then attach your content databases to the new farm. 2 blog posts that talk about using this method are here:
http://wssv3faq.mindsharp.com/Lists/v3%20WSS%20FAQ/DispForm.aspx?ID=136
http://webborg.blogspot.com/2007/06/reinstalling-sharepoint-wss3-to-run.html

The second option is to actually try and move all the databases (including the configdb) to the new server. Microsoft has documentation on how to do this (not specific to WIDB->SQL Server migrations, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.) My understanding of this though is that moving the configdb is not always seamless, and could cause you some big problems. Regardless, here is the documentation for this approach:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512723.aspx